# Why the upgrade to Flutter v0.7.3 beta stopped my application from running?

Tags: crash, flutter, upgrade

I have upgraded my Flutter version from 0.5.1 beta to 0.7.3 beta as few plugins were not working properly and I was suggested to upgrade to latest, both plugins and flutter itself. But, this has completely destroyed the application as it won't even start. Below is the Android Studio Run console output

```
Note: /Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.20/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.5.20/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuth.Plugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-1.0.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/storage/FirebaseStoragePlugin.java:293: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
Map<String, String> customMetadata = (Map<String, String>) map.get("customMetadata");
                                                                  ^
  required: Map<String,String>
  found:    Object
1 warning
Note: /Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker_multiple-0.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/ruiyu/imagepickermultiple/TransparentActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.`
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/apple/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player-0.6.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Finished with error: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'allElements' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: allElements("activity")
```

Below is the output from flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am sure the allElements() is not dart or flutter code. It's an inside Java code, means a plugin or Flutter itself is broken.

Comment: It does not say `getAllElements()`, but `allElements("activity")`. However, I believe you are correct anyway.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot yes now corrected.

Comment: `flutter clean` - just had this same problem today

Comment: @ReverseCold probably did that 100 times. Not the solution bro..

Answer (score 1):

I feel very embarrassed as it was my own doing which has brought this issue up. I finally fixed it by going to the Android manifest file and removed the offending

```
tools:replace="android:label"
```

which I had placed in the  tag for whatever reason I don't know. Then I do..

```
flutter clean
```

Then Run the app works! Voila!